# text/plain Content type return some <br> or line break to output in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-type, line-breaks

I have the following code in a [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) controller:

```
 $this->output->set_header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

along with

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

How come I see line breaks in the output?

```
1-
2-
3-
4- my output
```

Comment: What tool to you use to view the output ? Your browser ?

Comment: i see output by browse . http://localhost/test/index

Comment: Try to display source code of the page in the brower (it usually is ctrl+u). What do you see then?

Comment: yes there are lines break .....!

Comment: yes . only line break same \r\n

Comment: And what did you expect?

Comment: becouse in text/plain header tags will show

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your problem.

Comment: please check this url ..  http://rank.zhupin.ir/ajax/get_all_sites

Comment: check you have print <pre> in your code some where

Comment: how did you detect <pre>?